# Scroll to anchor position whilst taking into account fixed header, when freshly navigating to url with a hash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollview

Demo: https://6vk5zm231k.codesandbox.io/

I have a basic react app with a fixed header of 100px, and few links that scroll to the corresponding anchor sections. I am using 'react-scroll' which works as expected as it has a prop called 'offest'.

The problem is on the initial page load, if I navigate with a hash in the url (https://6vk5zm231k.codesandbox.io/#home, https://6vk5zm231k.codesandbox.io/#about, etc), I arrive at the section without the offset to take into account the menu height. Clicking the link in the menu will fix it because react-scroll does its job but I am not sure how to deal with the initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit dirty but you can force scroll to the desired component when componentDidMount() fires. Here's the fork of your project with scroll fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/1owj7yqm33

Comment: Thanks very much. Works really well. Please explain what you mean by -99px. I don't really understand.